# Any real-life example for Amber's Auth?

Tags: amber-framework

Basically all the guides show you how to use the generator to create a basic authentication system. But in real life there may be a need to add other fields to the user such as first_name, last_name, phone, address, country_id (fk to a countries table...)

Is this even possible with this generator? Or should I look into writing my own system from scratch?

Comment: The auth generator is pretty simple, but I have some ideas about this, you can find some Projects here: http://shards.info/repos/amberframework/amber/dependents (I'll comment you back when I found the right repo)

Comment: The auth generator is immature. There is some talk of providing an improvement, see issue here: https://github.com/amberframework/amber/issues/580

Comment: @nick-m the amber generator sets up the authentication portion, not the user profile portion. Any fields you add to the user object can make up a profile or a profile model can be scaffolded separately.

Comment: Hey vox. That’s what I suspected. Wasn’t sure whether I can mess with the columns it generates or I’d have to decouple, as I like to work with denormalized models for simplicity and performance reasons. In any case I decided to take a step back and wait to see what happens, amber and Crystal are promising but still bleeding edge, so I’m a bit reluctant to use them in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator gives you the very basic needed for Authentication. If you need to add more things to your user, you can always modify the class.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!